# "Stop-And-Wait" or "Stop-And-Wait ARQ"?

Tags: protocol-theory

I was reading about noisy and noiseless channels. Under "noiseless channels", it listed "stop-and-wait", and under "noisy channel", it listed "stop-and-wait ARQ". I was wondering what the difference is between these, or if they're actually the same thing and the one under "noiseless channel" is just a typo and should actually be "[stop-and-wait ARQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-wait_ARQ)"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ideal channel that can transmit successfully every time then there is no need for any error recovery.

When you have noise in the channel there is a probability of an error. So you need some form of error detection and recovery mechanism.